# SpaCy 'nlp.to_disk' is not saving to disk

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to figure out why my custom SpaCy NER model isn't saving to disk using **nlp.to_disk**. I am using this condition in my python script:

```
 # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)
```

The **output_dir** is defined at the top of my script as:

```
@plac.annotations(
    model=("Model name. Defaults to blank 'en' model.", "option", "m", str),
    output_dir=("Optional output directory", "option", "o", Path),
    n_iter=("Number of training iterations", "option", "n", int),
)
```

The model runs without any errors and all of the outputs are correct but it doesn't save to disk. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You output directory argument is optional. Are you sure you're providing it? Is the "Saved model to" printed?

Comment: The "Saved model to" does not print. Which should right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [polm23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355715/polm23) for getting me in the right direction!

I was not adding the option with my directory path defined. Here is what needed to be done to run the model and have it saved.

```
python train_ner.py -m=en -o=path/to/output/directory -n=1000
```

It was a silly rookie mistake on my part but I am very appreciative of the help.